# JMS Session Pooling with Message Listener

Tags: session, jms, message-listener

Relating to this question ([JMS Connection Pooling in Message Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27140595/jms-connection-pooling-in-message-listener)), i'm currently trying to build a session pool upon a pool of connections that i'd created earlier.

I had managed to create a pool of JMS Connections and when i run it with my Producers and Consumers, they work fine. The Consumers is registered with a Message Listener to retrieve messages from the MQ.

However when i implemented the session pool, the message listener just stop working. The producers can send message out without problem, but the message listener never fired off.

The following code is the `create` code in the `JmsSessionObjectFactory`:

```
Connection connection = Application.getInstance().getConnectionPool().borrowObject();
Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
Application.getInstance().getConnectionPool().returnObject(connection);
```

Is that the correct way to implement the factory creation for a session? Or my concept of session pooling with the connection pool is wrong?

Appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Comment: are you running this on an app server or a standalone way? what JMS impl?

Comment: this is run as a standalone app. the app is listening on a port to receive info and send them over JMS Producer to a IBM MQ, and also register Consumer with `MessageListener` to retrieve message from the MQ

Comment: post some code, otherwise, it's impossible to know what you're doing beyond your description. BTW, JMS connections are thread-safe,